# Bottom Sheet Behavior scroll on showing Snackbar

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-snackbar, snackbar, bottom-sheet

I have no clue to start implementing this desired behavior:

A bottom sheet is expanded on the screen and the Snackbar is shown up after user's interaction. The issue is that the Snackbar covers part of the bottom sheet content. I want the bottom sheet to scroll up on Snackbar showing (like FAB behavior).

Comment: Are you using coordinate layout as parent in this ?

Comment: No, but I use BottomSheetDialogFragment; so I don't know how to set the behavior to it